# Reading CPU usage

Tags: linux, arch-linux, resource-monitor

I am building a Linux, web-based resource monitor.

For now I am looking forward to use:

- `df` for reading HDD usage status
- `/proc/meminfo` (through cat) for reading RAM status
- `mpstat` (from sysstat package) for reading CPU usage

While the `df` and `/proc/meminfo` returns the data almost instantly, `mpstat` delays for the interval I specify - with the minimum accepted value being 1 (in seconds).

Is there a real-time CPU usage reader, or is there a way to make `mpstat` return "instantly"?

#### mpstat output:

```
[psycketom@stone ~]# mpstat -P ALL 1 1
Linux 3.5.4-1-ARCH (stone)      03/05/2013      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

11:33:15 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
11:33:16 AM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
11:33:16 AM    0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Average:     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
Average:     all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
Average:       0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
```

Comment: I don't know mpstat. Can you provide an example output please?

Comment: @mpy, Q updated with example.

Comment: Is `top` not suited to your purposes for some reason?

Comment: I'm looking for a direct output to `STDOUT`, which I could grep. `top` continuously polls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `top` in batch mode and a single iteration:

```
top -bn 1
```

I would also use `free` instead of parsing `meminfo`.

Another way is to use `ps`, add the CPU% of each process and divide by the number of cores that your machine has:

```
ps axo pcpu | 
 gawk -v cores=`grep -m 1 cores /proc/cpuinfo | cut -d ' ' -f 3` \
      -v cpus=`grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo` \
         '{k+=$1}END{print k/(cores * cpus);}'
```

If your system has only one core, the above script will fail, producing:

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=83) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

In order to make it run, change `k/(cores * cpus)` to `k/(cores==""?1:cores * cpus)`. This will check whether the `cores` variable is not empty, if it is, `1` will be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the `free` tip, and looks like I am gonna stick with `top` then. Accepted!

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me, that `top` does not reflect the real usage. I made about 60 web-requests to the server, and all of them stayed on 97.7% idle, even though the table showed usage at 5.8% for `top`. I mean, it showed 97.7% in the header `%Cpu(s):  1.5 us,  0.6 sy,  0.1 ni, 97.7 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st`. Do I have to read the total usage from somewhere else or should I calculate on my end?

Comment: @psycketom The table showed `5.8%` usage of a _single_ core for top. The percentages are for each individual core. So, if `foo` is taking 40% of a single core of a 2-core machine, `top` will show `40%` for `foo`, not `20%` as you might expect. Also see my updated answer for another way of getting actual usage.

Comment: Since my system has only one core, this ended up in a error. Changing to `k/(cores==""?1:cores * cpus)` fixed the problem.